Who wins the Scrambler-Solver game for infinitary Rubik's cubes?
Given a suitable infinitary analogue $\mathcal Q$ of the Rubik's cube (as developed below), consider the two player game played between the Scrambler and the Solver wherein the Scrambler scrambles the cube by a (possibly infinite) sequence of twists (without the Solver watching), presents the scrambled cube to the Solver, and the Solver attempts to unscramble it by a sequence of twists. The Solver wins after $\omega$ many twists if $\mathcal Q$ is returned to its original "solved" configuration, otherwise the Scrambler wins. Can the Solver win in general?
The cube
Let $L$ be a linear order with no greatest element, write its reverse as $-L$. Consider the order $L^\dagger = -L + \hat1 + L$ where $\hat 1$ is the singleton order $1$ but its element, say $\hat 0 \in L^\dagger$, should be distinguished among the elements of $L^\dagger$. Having a distinguished center element in the order is analogous to ordinary Rubik's cubes of odd side length. The foremost examples I have in mind are $L = \omega$, $L = \mathbb Q^+$, and $L = \mathbb R^+$. In these cases, $L^\dagger$ as an order is just $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb R$, respectively, but again, there is a distinguished element (in particular, there are no automorphic translations of the structure $\langle L^\dagger, \hat 0\rangle$).
Now, we imagine the $L^\dagger \times L^\dagger \times L^\dagger$ cube $\mathcal Q$ as six $L^\dagger \times L^\dagger$ "grids" arranged like the faces of a cube centered a the origin in $x,y,z$ coordinates with $(\hat 0,\hat 0)$ on the axes.  The point is that we have corresponding positions in opposite faces and we can refer to particular "planes" within $\mathcal Q$—such as the $x = \alpha$ plane for $\alpha \in L^\dagger$—in which the twists will take place. To have some notation, let's introduce two new elements $\pm\infty$, thought of as bookending $L^\dagger$. We can think of $\mathcal Q$ as embedded in $[-\infty,+\infty]^3 = (\{-\infty\} + L^\dagger + \{+\infty\})^3$ with the faces in the $\pm\infty$ planes. A cell is a point in one of the faces.
Twists
Define a positive orientation in each axis plane, call it clockwise. A twist $T_{i,\alpha}$ where $i \in \{x,y,z\}$ is a permutation of the cells in the $i=\alpha$ plane given by a clockwise quarter turn. For example, the twist $T_{x,\hat 0}$ takes $(\hat 0,\alpha,+\infty)$ to $(\hat 0,-\infty,\alpha)$ and similarly for the other three edges. Clockwise quarter turns suffice to do any manipulation. Given a twist $T$, we'll write $T^{-1} = T^3$ for the inverse (counterclockwise) twist, whenever useful.
In a standard Rubik's cube the individual pieces that make up the puzzle are called cubies. We will refer to the (exposed) faces of a cubies as tiles. Nota bene, cells and tiles are not to be confused. Cells are particular locations on $\mathcal Q$, as seen from $[-\infty,+\infty]^3$, they do not move with twists, whereas tiles move between cells.
A key property of a standard Rubik's cube is that a twist in any of the outermost planes permutes not only the tiles in the four rows at that coordinate, but also all the tiles in the adjacent face. We definitely would like to be able to make such a face twist, and so we also define $T_{i,\pm\infty}$ to do just this. For instance $T_{x,+\infty}$ permutes the tiles in the $x = +\infty$ face by a clockwise quarter turn about $(\hat0,\hat0)$. There are no corner or edge cubies, so this twist acts non-trivially on only these cells, quite different from an ordinary Rubik's cube.
Configurations and legal twist sequences
A configuration $f$ of $\mathcal Q$ is an assignment to every cell one of seven colors among $\Gamma = \{r,g,b,o,w,y,\perp\}$ (red, green, blue, orange, white, yellow, not a color). The solved configuration $f_{\text{solved}}$ is the particular constant color assignment $\{x=+\infty\} \mapsto r$, $\{x=-\infty\} \mapsto o$, $\{y=+\infty\} \mapsto w$, $\{y=+\infty\} \mapsto y$, $\{z=+\infty\} \mapsto g$, $\{z=-\infty\} \mapsto b$.
Twists act on the space of configurations in the obvious way. Namely, $f' = T\cdot f$ is the configuration $f'(c) = f(T^{-1}c)$ for every cell $c$. We will be pushed to consider infinite sequences of twists, and this is where the $\perp$ color comes into play. Namely, we'd like to have a well defined configuration after executing infinitely many twists. Given a sequence of twists $\langle T_\eta : \eta < \theta\rangle$ for some ordinal $\theta$ and and initial configuration $f_0$, we can define subsequent configurations $f_{\eta+1} = T_\eta\cdot f_\eta$ and at limit stages $\lambda$, set $f_\lambda(c) = \gamma$ if the value of $\langle f_\eta(c) : \eta < \lambda\rangle$ (i.e., the history of the colors of cell $c$ up to stage $\lambda$) had eventually stabilized on $\gamma$, otherwise, we set $f_\lambda(c) = {\perp}$.
Our main interest is merely $\omega$-sequences of twists, for which the above can be stated as follows. After $\omega$ many twists, if any cell had changed color infinitely often, its value is $\perp$, otherwise, it retains its limiting value.
We'll say a configuration is legal if and only if no cell has color $\perp$. Given a legal initial configuration and a sequence of twists (in particular, an $\omega$-sequence), we'll say the sequence of twists is legal if every obtained configuration is legal including the final limiting one if there is one.
The Scrambler-Solver game
The Scrambler scrambles the cube by performing a legal $\le\omega$ sequence of twists (hidden from the solver) starting from the solved configuration, resulting in some legal "scrambled" configuration $g_0$. The Solver sees the configuration $g_0$ and may execute any $\le \omega$ sequence of twists.
The Solver wins if the solved configuration is attained at or before stage $\omega$, otherwise the Scrambler wins.

Does the Solver have a winning strategy? When can they win before stage $\omega$? Certain instances are clear. For example, if we only allow finite scrambles and $L$ is countable, then there are only countably many possible twists, and so the Solver can systematically execute and undo every finite sequence of twists, eventually exactly undoing the scramble, and this will happen at a finite stage. This argument completely fails if $L$ is uncountable or if the scramble is infinite. Indeed, even if the Solver is allowed to observe the infinite scramble, she cannot simply "undo" it, since the reverse sequence is not well-ordered. This invites the question, are some (legal) scrambles unsolvable even in principal? If so, does it help to allow the Solver $> \omega$ many moves?

If the scramble is computable, can the Solver win? Can she win computably?



Very nice question. But have you defined the quarter turn properly? I would expect $(\hat 0,\infty,-\alpha)$.

You've presented the question as a game, but as I see it, the core question is simply whether infinite convergent scrambles can be unscrambled. Essentially, is this a group? Is that right?

@JoelDavidHamkins I think the quarter turn definition is simply a matter of which rotation direction one takes as "clockwise". In my example, I was imagining the $x,y,z$ coordinates with $+x$ to the right, $+y$ upward, and $+z$ towards myself and "clockwise" according to the right-hand-rule. So in an $x$ twist $T_{x,\hat 0}$, the "front" cell $(\hat 0,\alpha,+\infty)$ is twisted to the "bottom" cell $(\hat 0, -\infty, -\alpha)$. But your suggestion works just as well so long as the rotations are defined consistently.

@JoelDavidHamkins I agree that the core question is indeed whether infinite convergent scrambles can be unscrambled. Definitely, the twists form a group (which acts on the configuration space) but it seems to me that the group structure alone cannot suffice to answer questions about infinite sequences. Four twists are the identity but a the action of a constant sequence of twists need not converge. Moreover, whether or not (the action of) a given sequence of twists converges depends on the initial configuration, not just the sequence of twists.

I'm still confused about your rotations, since under your description I think you should mean $(\hat 0,-\infty,\alpha)$ then. That is, there should be only one $-$ sign, not two. In 2D, for example, a quarter turn rotates $(x,y)$ counterclockwise to $(-y,x)$ or clockwise to $(y,-x)$, not $(-y,-x)$. And yes, about the group, I was referring to the question whether the infinite convergent operations form a group.

@JoelDavidHamkins Ah yes of course, thanks for that correction, I've fixed that. I think I agree with your group formulation of the question regarding infinite operations. But also, even for finite scrambles, obviously, they are invertible, but I'd still like to know in the case that $L$ is uncountable, given only the scrambled configuration, can the Solver always find the inverse just by inspection? Or can/must she use $\ge \omega$ many twists to search for it? (I think the game perspective invites these kinds of questions.)

Do you know if you can unscramble the operation of doing every twist exactly once in some sort of organized $\omega$-enumeration? It seems that this will be convergent, since any tile location is affected by only three twists, but it seems that we can in effect move a tile to infinity in the limit, making it in effect disappear, which would suggest you can't invert the whole operation. For example, this phenomenon also happens with infinite convergent compositions of permutations on an infinite set. See https://mathoverflow.net/a/17655/1946

No, I guess it isn't clear how to move a tile to infinity that way without repeating twists. Is there a simple (or any) convergent scramble that uses some twist infinitely many times, but is not possible with only finitely many of each twist?

@JoelDavidHamkins that's a good question, I will think about the every twist once operation. I don't think tiles can escape to infinity, though, unless I've misunderstood your meaning. Like an ordinary Rubik's cube, each tile can only ever occupy up to 24 distinct cells (corresponding four on each face). (This is why, e.g., illegal configurations are persistent.)

I think this question has great potential, but as it is currently phrased it is very confusing (although I admit it is rigorously defined). IIUC, as per @JoelDavidHamkins's comment, this isn't at all about games but about accessibility in a certain graph. Basically you have a group of finite operations which you “complete” into something that might not be a group but is still, at least, an oriented graph (with edges being “accessible in $\leq\omega$ moves”) and you are asking whether any out-neighbor of the origin is also an in-neighbor, or something of the sort. [contd.]

[contd.] If my understanding is correct, I suspect that very little about this depends on the details of what the cube is like: it's probably more of a question of what kinds of conditions should be imposed for the “completion” process to yield something sane (and, hopefully, a group, or at least something symmetric). Couldn't you find a simpler and/or more general situation than an infinite Rubik's cube in which this “completion” makes sense, and start by studying this?

@JackEdwardTisdell About the 24, yes, I had come to the same conclusion myself, and that is what I had meant when saying it isn't possible without repeating twists. Meanwhile, I guess every infinite scramble that uses every twist only finitely often will be convergent, and my question is whether these are exactly the convergent scrambles.

@Gro-Tsen, I appreciate the feedback, this is for sure a useful change in perspective and I will think more along these lines. In defence of the peculiar set-up, as I see it, the underlying group structure is motivated by the Rubik's cube operations and there's a sense in which the "sanity" of this completion process (if it turns out to be non-trivial) is justified by the Rubik's cube interpretation. But certainly I agree that's it's worth thinking about this completion process in a more general context.

Every tile is part of a 2×2×2 Rubik's subcube, and indeed any finitely many tiles are part of a finite Rubik's subcube. So can we solve the countable case by solving and then preserving increasingly large finite subcubes? I guess the problem is that we have to temporarily upset the solved part to solve larger parts.

@JoelDavidHamkins I think I have a convergent scramble only attainable using some twist infinitely often if we allow half-turns $T^2$ as single operations, although a Rubik's cube expert might correct me. Take $L=\omega$. Apply half-turn twists in $x = \pm n$ then do a quarter turn face twist in the $\pm y,\pm z$ faces, call this group element $s_n$. Note $s_n^2$ results in a kind of windowpane pattern in the $z,y$ faces. $s_0^2,s_1^2,...$ yields an asterisk pattern in the $z,y$ faces but leaves the $x$ faces pristine. I don't think this is doable without infinitely many $y,z$ face twists.

@JackEdwardTisdell Another issue is that you've described the set-up in terms of an order, and perhaps that is how we imagine it geometrically, but it seems to me that the order doesn't matter. You have a set $L$ and another copy of it $-L$. Is this correct?

@JoelDavidHamkins I believe you are correct, the order may not matter. So long as we distinguish the "center" cell between $L$ and $-L$ (or the center cut in the "even" version), the definitions still work. However, there is a subtlety regarding whether or not $L$ has an "outermost" element (greatest in the order formulation); I stipulated in the OP that it does not for if $L$ has a distinguished "outermost" element, then it seems we should want edge and corner cubies which carry more than one tile. Intuitively, "$\mathbb Z^3$" has no such cubies while "$(\mathbb Q\cap[-1,1])^3$" does.
